# Блокирование каждого второго клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как мне блокировать каждый второй клик по ссылке?
То есть пользователь нажимает на ссылку - вылетает блок, затем закрывается. Пользователь нажимает опять на ссылку - блок не вылетает. Пользователь нажимает опять на ссылку, и блок снова вылетает. И так далее.

```
$('.win').click(function() {
    $('.sage').slideDown('fast');
    $('.sage').delay(0).slideUp('fast'); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxjrfwxv/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать флаг:

```
var toShow = true;
$('.win').click(function()
{
    if (toShow)
    {
        $('.sage').slideDown('fast');
        $('.sage').delay(0).slideUp('fast'); 
    }
    toShow = !toShow;
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxjrfwxv/1/).

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @gm-111 на здоровье.